# Magento 2 - Wrong logo url in Newsletter Template

Tags: magento, magento2

- Magento ver. 2.1.4
- PHP 7.0.25
- Nginx 1.10.2
- Mode: Production

I create **Newsletter Template** with **Template Content**:

```
{{template config_path="design/email/header_template"}}
TEST TEXT
{{template config_path="design/email/footer_template"}}
```

Then i make Newsletter Queue and on my email box comes email without logo image;
On debug i saw, that logo lies in the folder: http://SITE.DOMAIN/static/version1510233956/frontend/vendor-magento/vendor-magento/en_US/Magento_Email/logo_email.png
And i can see image when open that url. But email template try to take logo from folder:
http://SITE.DOMAIN/pub/static/version1510585793/frontend/vendor-magento/vendor-magento/en_US/Magento_Email/logo_email.png
And there no image.

When i try to debug this bug on another machine with apache: logo lies in the folder http://SITE.DOMAIN/static/version1510569003/frontend/vendor-magento/vendor-magento/en_US/Magento_Email/logo_email.png and email template take image from this folder. As result i saw logo image in email message.

So, what could be the reason that on the "nginx - production server" does not display the logo image?

Answer (score 0):

Try this : turn off version numbers for the static files.

Store -> Configuration -> Developer -> Static Files Settings -> Sign Static Files